# Compose ViewMatrix and ProjectionMatrix

Tags: matrix

As the title says, you are able to compose the ViewMatrix and the ProjectionMatrix into one instead of multiplying a vector by the individual matrices.

Instead of doing this at run time for each item:
Vector * ViewMatrix -> Vector ProjectionMatrix

Do this at the start:
ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix -> ComposedMatrix

Then when drawing vectors:
Vector * ComposedMatrix

This would minimize the number of necessary matrix multiplications. Is there any reason not to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's what people do. Matrix multiplication is (theoretically) associative, so $((vA)B)C = v(ABC)$.

Comment: But usually it is projectionmatrix * viewmatrix * positionvector